# Getting error while creating a new task in Jira using jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jira, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to create an issue in Jira using Jenkinsfile, Code below:

```
echo "Connecting with jira"
withEnv(['JIRA_SITE=******']) {
def testIssue = [fields: [ project: [id: 10000],
summary: "New JIRA Created from Jenkins.",
description: "New JIRA Created from Jenkins.",
                       issuetype: [id: 3]]]
 response = jiraNewIssue issue: testIssue
  echo response.successful.toString()
  echo response.data.toString()
```

But while connecting to Jira, it is showing me error :

```
Connecting with jira
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] jiraNewIssue
JIRA: Site - ****** - Creating new issue:
IssueInput(fields=FieldsInput(summary=New JIRA Created from Jenkins.,
description=New JIRA Created from Jenkins., issuetype=IssueType(id=3,
description=null, name=null, subtask=null), project=Project(id=10000,
key=null, name=null, description=null, lead=null, components=null,
versions=null, issueTypes=null, projectCategory=null), labels=null,
assignee=null, components=null, fixVersions=null))
Error Code: 400
Error Message: {"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"customfield_10200":"QA
Owner is required."}}
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
**ERROR: {"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"customfield_10200":"QA Owner is
required."}}**
Finished: FAILURE
```

Could any one please let me know where should I add that custom field "QA Owner".

Answer (score 0):

This will work by passing in custom field - QA Owner

```
echo "Connecting with jira"
withEnv(['JIRA_SITE=******']) {
def testIssue = [fields: [ project: [id: 10000],
summary: "New JIRA Created from Jenkins.",
description: "New JIRA Created from Jenkins.",
                   issuetype: [id: 3],
                   "customfield_10200": { "name": "ABC" } 
 ]]            
response = jiraNewIssue issue: testIssue
    echo response.successful.toString()
echo response.data.toString()
```

Where abc is the Jira ID of QA Owner.